# Match according to several variables, some exactly and some with a range of variation

Tags: r, dataframe, match

```r
match1 <- semi_join(datosvendor, datosclient,
                    by=c("DAY","HOUR","MINUTE","ANUM","BNUM","DURATION"))
```

I want to make a match between the calls of two data frames according to the variables that appear in the previous line of code (day, hour, minute, number A, number B and duration) in an exact way. But I also want to add another variable to make the match, but not in an exact way: I also want to add the seconds of the call ("SECOND"), but taking into account that I want to make the match not with the exact second but with a range of 3 seconds up and down. That is to say, I want the call of a data frame to match with the one of another, taking into account that they can vary up to three seconds up and down (but they have to match exactly in all the other columns).

Note: my two data frames do not have the same dimension.

How would be the syntax to add this new variable to match also according to it along with all the others?

Comment: You are looking for a type of "non-equi" join, which is supported by `data.table`, `sqldf`, `fuzzyjoin`. `dplyr 1.1.0+` supports "inequality joins" but requires you pre-calculate the min and max range of the join before the join step. Regardless of what method you use, in your example I'd suggest combining year/day/hour/minute/second into a POSIXct datetime, since otherwise you will miss joins between, say, 5:00:01 pm and 4:59:59 pm, which is only two seconds away but which has different hour and minute.

Comment: In dplyr 1.1.0+, assuming you have converted your year/day/hour/minute/second into datetime "DATETIME" in both tables, you could use something like `semi_join(datosvendor, datosclient |> mutate(DATETIME_low = DATETIME - 3, DATETIME_high = DATETIME + 3), join_by(BNUM, DURATION, DATETIME >= DATETIME_low, DATETIME <= DATETIME_high))`

Comment: btw, you could use something like `datosvendor <- datosvendor |> mutate(DATETIME = lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(YEAR, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND))` to make a new DATETIME column.